# In App Purchase vs Free and Paid versions - ios

Tags: ios, ios5, in-app-purchase

I know this has been asked in the past, but I have seen no new posts since the hacking issues that took place in July regarding in app purchases.

I would like to use the in app purchase system to allow a user to remove ads from my application.  This seems like a much cleaner solution than maintaining 2 separate apps (free and paid).

I would appreciate any feedback others have on this topic.  I know apple has implemented a fix to stop the hacking.. but still wanted some input from the SO user community.

Thank you.

Comment: are u using ios6 if yes you don't have to worry about the hack issue anymore as this has been addressed

Comment: the app will be usable on ios5.x as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Apple's [VerificationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html) to validate the receipts you get and you can safely use IAP under iOS 5.x. In my own app I use this regardless of the iOS version (5 or 6).

Comment: do u know what's been added on ios 6 regarding this hack?

Comment: @tiguero - No I don't. There may be details in [Apple's developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios) in the IAP section.